# What is different between yarn mode and deploy mode in spark?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I'm very confused right now.
Please check if this is right.

4 cases command like below:

```
# It mean, yarn is cluster mode and deploy cluster mode.
# cluster have YARN Container(have Spark AM, Spark Driver) and YARN node manager.
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster

# It mean, yarn is cluster mode and deploy client mode.
# client have Spark Driver.
# cluster have YARN Container(have Spark AM, Spark Driver) and YARN node manager.
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client

# It mean, yarn is client mode and deploy cluster mode.
# cluster have YARN Container(have Spark AM) and YARN node manager.
spark-submit --master yarn-client --deploy-mode cluster

# It mean, yarn is client mode and deploy client mode.
# client have Spark Driver.
# cluster have YARN Container(have Spark AM) and YARN node manager.
spark-submit --master yarn-client --deploy-mode client
```

Is the explanation of the above code correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#Use yarn, deploy the driver into the yarn cluster.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster
```

#Use yarn, deploy the driver on my local machine(machine that is launching the code)

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client # this is the default if you don't specify --deploy-mode
```

These aren't [actual options](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) anymore so they aren't really worth discussing:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --deploy-mode cluster
spark-submit --master yarn-client --deploy-mode client
```

`--master yarn-client` maybe was an option in early version of spark but isn't used today. (as referenced in the documentation above)